# Aparecer janela modal uma vez

Tags: javascript, modal

Estou com dificuldades em fazer com que a janela modal pareça apenas uma vez.

No JS

```
test("modal shows up", function() {
  equal($('.sweet-alert').length, 0);

  swal({
  title: "Amigo da FAST FUSO<br>ATENÇÃO!",
  text: "Estamos sofrendo com um grande problema de comunicação.<br>Estamos com problemas em nosso tronco-chave da VIVO, dificultando muito a comunicação com vocês. <br>(SEM PREVISÃO DE CONCERTO POR PARTE DA VIVO)<br> Durante este processo informamos telefones que estão funcionando enquanto não regularizamos a situação de nosso troco-chave.<br> TELEFONES DE CONTATO:<br>(11) 3409-3675<br> (11) 2884-8410 <br>(11) 3409-2805<br>(11) 3405-0932 <br>(11) 3405-0542<br> e-mail de contato: vendas@fastfuso.com.br<br> Agradecemos a ajuda e compreensão de todos.", 
  html: true
});

  ok($('.sweet-alert').is(':visible'));

});
```

No CSS

```
body.stop-scrolling {   height: 100%;   overflow: hidden; }

.sweet-overlay {   background-color: black;   /* IE8 */   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)";   /* IE8 */   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);   position: fixed;   left: 0;   right: 0;   top: 0;   bottom: 0;   display: none;   z-index: 10000; }

.sweet-alert {   background-color: white;   font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;   width: 800px;   padding: 17px;   border-radius: 5px;   text-align: center;   position: fixed;   left: 50%;   top: 50%;   margin-left: -400px;   margin-top:
-200px;   overflow: hidden;   display: none;   z-index: 99999; }
```

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta e ser mais claro com o problema, por favor? Ele o modal aparece mais de uma vez?

Comment: o modal abrir apenas 1 vez , mesmo depois de recarregar página novamente

Comment: Por que não tenta utilizar cookies. Uma vez eu estava com o mesmo propósito que o seu, e me sugeriram utilizar cookies. Porém, no meu caso, meu sistema já utilizava php. O seu utiliza?